# Game of Life - data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, conways-game-of-life

what is the best data structure for implementing Game Of Life in Java?

My board is growing constantly and the order of the element is important.

I was thinking about using Set , however the order of the elements is not promised me.

I cannot use N x M array, as the matrix changes after every generation..

Comment: This forum is not for information exchange. For theoretical question such as yours, post them on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), or similar exchange sites.

Comment: `Set` is just an interface. You need to decide which implementation of Set you use. Like TreeSet, HashSet or LinkedHashSet.

Comment: If you are referring to Conway's Game of Life, you may want to consider R2-D2 answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).